# CSS class under # selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply a style to a specific item of a CSS menu.  The CSS menu has a

```
<div id="cssmenu">   </div>
```

So all of the items in the .css file are `#cssmenu li ul {` etc.  However, I want to apply a style to the headers of the menu, so I am trying to add:

```
<li class="header"><a>Menu Header</a></li>
```

When I try to add styles to my .css using `.header` class, the styles do not appear to be being applied.  Do I need to be nesting the class CSS, like `#cssmenu .header` or something?

**EDIT:**

Here is the CSS:

```
#cssmenu {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu li ul {
    /*margin-top: 0px; submenu location relative to bottom of parent */
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#cssmenu li ul li a {
    width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > a {
    background: #99CC99; /* parent background when hovering over child */
/* shadow around parent when hover */
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #000;

    /*border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;*/
}
#cssmenu li a {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
}
#cssmenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #99CC99;
    padding: 12px 12px 11px 12px; /* link background when hover over link */
}
#cssmenu li ul {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9); /* child menu background w/ transparency */
    padding: 10px 5px;

    box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #BBB;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #BBB;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #BBB;

    border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
/* display sub-menu as list */
#cssmenu li ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu li ul li a, #nav li ul li a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: #000;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#cssmenu li ul li a:hover {
    /*text-decoration: underline;*/
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu .menuheader {
    color: #bbb;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
  <li class="menuheader"><a>Store</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="products.htm">Essential Oil Blends</a></li>
      ....
    </ul>
  </li>
.....
```

Comment: have you tried `#cssmenu .header`?

Comment: No you don't need to be that specific. Just calling the class will work. Can we see what your CSS looks like?

Comment: Google "CSS specificity rules"

Comment: @Kolby `#cssmenu li ul` is more specific (`102`) than `.header` (`010`)

Comment: By the way, <li> should be inside <ul>. Hence, #cssmenu ul li

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, I know. But he shouldn't have to be more specific. Just calling the class should be fine.

Comment: Show us your code. This might just be a minor confusion and can easily be resolved. :o)

Comment: I have tried `#cssmenu .header`.  Is the reason that didn't work because `#cssmenu li ul` is more specific than `.header`??

Comment: I have added the relevant CSS/HTML to my post.  It is probably something simple, but I am no expert with CSS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#cssmenu .header` should work.

Check this example I created: http://jsfiddle.net/74JQQ/2/

Here is a simple reference regarding CSS selectors:

`#` is used for id's while `.` is for classes (which you already know).

A space between selections mean you are looking at all descendant elements.

A `>` symbol means you are looking only at direct children elements.

Example:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="header"><a>Header1</a></li>
        <li class="header"><a>Header2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a>Footer</a>
</div>
```

`#cssmenu .header` will select the two `<li>`

`.header` will select the two `<li>`

`#cssmenu > .header` will not select anything since there is no element with the class "header" that is a direct child of `#cssmenu`.

`#cssmenu a` will select all 3 `<a>` elements.

`#cssmenu > a` will only select the last `<a>` element (which reads Footer).

Comment: This was very informative.  I am "fiddling" with the fiddle to try to get the style to match what I am looking for, which is much easier.

Comment: Nice.  I am wondering, could you help me with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GJKLR/1   I am trying to get the first menu header to look red (so I know style was applied).  I have tried a bunch of different specificities, but none seem to apply.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out.  I was using the text color to try to determine if the style was being applied, but in reality the style was being overridden.  Since the text color is not going to matter in the final style, I tried it with background, and that style was applied.  Your explanation of selectors was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```
#cssmenu:nth-child(1){
/* Here the style you want to add */
}
```

As it should give to the first child of the element with `id="cssmenu"` the style you define.